# How can I use "groupby()" for gathering country names?

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have three columns pandas dataframe; the name of the country, year and value. The year starts from 1960 to 2020 for each country.

The data looks like that;

| Country Name | Year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 1960 | 12 |
| Italy | 1960 | 8 |
| Spain | 1960 | 5 |
| Italy | 1961 | 35 |
| USA | 1961 | 50 |

I would like to gather same country names. How can I do it? I could not succeed using groupby()ç Groupby() always requires functions like sum().

| Country Name | Year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 1960 | 12 |
| USA | 1961 | 50 |
| Italy | 1960 | 8 |
| Italy | 1961 | 35 |
| Spain | 1960 | 5 |
| Spain | 1960 | 5 |

Comment: Could you please clarify what does gathering country names mean. Is it list of country across dataframe or list of country by year

Comment: For example, I would like to see all USA together one under the other, from 1960 to 2020. Of course, not only for USA it is just an example. USA 1960 then USA 1961 and then USA 1961. @Ashwiniku918